# SimpleRepository and abstraction

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

I've been using Sub Sonic 3.x.x.x and I've come across something I need help with.
I'm using an abstract class and a factory pattern etc...
and this is basically the problem:

```
public abstract class Person
{
}

public class Male : Person
{
}

public class Female : Person
{
}

....
```

How do I get this to work?

```
String personType = "male";
Type myType = GetPersonTypeFromFactory(personType);

SimpleRepository rep = new SimpleRepository();

var all = rep.All<...>().ToList();
```

I can't put `rep.All<myType>` so how can I get this working?

Comment: Out of curiosity why is your Person class abstract? I'm sure there's a reason but I can't see it from your code

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleRepository cannot persist object that are abstract. I can't speak to ActiveRecord however.

I'm sure you know this, but if you did use SimpleRepository and you're looking to get all of one type you could do `rep.All<Male>()`. This eliminates your Factory and I'm sure the example is a simplified from what you're doing in the real world so this probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It’s worth bearing in mind that de-serialising abstract objects is always a pain in the ass as abstract classes don’t have a default constructor; having said that, there is nothing stopping you de-serialising to a concrete class, and returning and interface/abstract class from your factory.
When you persist/retrieve data to the DB you just do it via your concrete DO object and instantiate your BO object in the factory via a copy constructor and have it implement the same interface as the DO object.  But as always with patterns, you’ve got to ask what you’re getting for the code.

To retrieve :
DO --> Factory --> BO

To Store :
BO --> Façade/Controller --> DO

DO and BO implement IYourObject interface, or derive from YourObjectBase, which has the copy constructor YourObjectBase(YourObjectBase src).

Lots of lines of code though if you don’t have multiple BO types :-)